# CSS Toggle Switch com <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Estou precisando fazer a transição desse script para usar com `<select>`.

Veja bem o script funcionando é assim
    http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/css-toggle-switch/

Meus selects (mais de 88) sao APENAS nesse estilo:

```
<select>
<option value="0">Off</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
</select>
```

Apenas com opcao de ligar e desligar (0,1)

Gostaria de poder adaptar o CSS para isso, mas vejo que é CSS3 e nao sei trabalhar com ele.. O que posso fazer?

Exemplo de como seria http://jsfiddle.net/thebestclassdsfgf/jo2hkom2/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse código é feito para um `input type="checkbox"` e o CSS faz o trabalho todo. Ou seja se o input estiver `:checked` ou não, o botão mexe-se. No seu caso [poderia funcionar assim também](http://jsfiddle.net/7m8L2b74/), com inputs.

Mas se quiser mesmo usar `select` pode fazer assim usando uma classe `ligado` para substituir a funcionalidade do `:checked`

HTML

```
<select id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" >
    <option value="0">Off</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
</select>
<label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
```

jQuery

```
$('select').on('click', function () {
     $(this).val(this.value == '1' ? '0' : '1');
    this.classList.toggle('ligado');
});
```

CSS (somente a parte relevante)

```
.cmn-toggle-round.ligado + label:before {
    background-color: #8ce196;
}
.cmn-toggle-round.ligado + label:after {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8u1beek/

Comment: perfeito! Mas eu teria problemas, pois eu ja pre defino quem ta marcado ou nao usando o `selected="selected"` e nesse caso nao funcionou..

Comment: @user3163662 ok, isso é simples, só precis de juntar mais uma linha: http://jsfiddle.net/7m8L2b74/2/

Comment: Ok, agora estou tendo problemas, ele nao altera o valor.. e como eu vou enviar por post, preciso que mude. Veja (altere o toggle e espere) jsfiddle.net/thebestclassdsfgf/7m8L2b74/3 @Sergio

Comment: @user3163662 e porque não fazer isso com checkbox?

Comment: @Segio estou fazendo transições.. e sao muitas checkboxes

Comment: @user3163662 editei a resposta para mudar o valor do select quando receber um clic

Comment: muito obrigado, com sua ajuda consegui =)

Comment: @user3163662 boa!